# Using file.seek() with arduino ide

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I have in my code in c, this function:

```c
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

I need to use the same function with Arduino ide. Is this correct?

```c
    file.seek(file.size());
```

Or what is the alternative function in Arduino ide?

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/sd/seek/

Comment: Just try it and see what happens.  That will be way faster than asking.

Comment: It can be faster to look up the documentation than wait hours for someone to answer.

Comment: OT, to clarify technical terms: The Arduino **IDE** is just that, an integrated development environment. It does _not provide_ functions or classes, it just _recognizes_ the names and therefore give you some support. The real thing you mean are the Arduino **libraries**, [the reference of which](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/) you should bookmark in your browser. However, an installation puts all of this on your computer. (There is more, for example the compiler system...) You can use each without the other.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/sd/seek/ :

#### SD - seek()

Seek to a new position in the file, which must be between 0 and the size of the file (inclusive).

#### Syntax

```
file.seek(pos)
```

#### Parameters

- file: an instance of the File class (returned by SD.open()).
- pos: the position to which to seek (unsigned long).

---

If you want to seek to the start of the file, therefore you should seek to zero, not `file.size()`. Using `file.size()` would seek to the end of the file.